# Create Datasource in Application.cfc

Tags: coldfusion

I would like to set up a datasource in my Application.cfc
Can I do it somehow with dbsetup?

I would like to name the source, specify server, database, user, password,....

My Administrator doesn't work on the server, that's why I want to do it this way.

Comment: Sounds like you may be confusing `Application.cfc` with the [Administrator API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fcf.html)? You cannot *create* a datasource in an Application.cfc. Creating a datasource is a one time event and requires access to the CF Administrator or Administrator API as @Travis mentioned. (After the dsn is created, you can use it in your Application.cfc, but that is something totally different.)  RE: *"My Administrator doesn't work on the server"* What do you mean by that? Are you on a shared server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [administrator API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fcf.html) to create it if you have the administrator password. I'm not sure if you should be doing this in your application.cfc though.  CF6+ took away the ability to use DSN-Less connections natively so you can't make a single use DSN unless you want to [jump through a lot of hoops](http://www.neiland.net/blog/article/how-to-create-a-dsn-less-database-connection-in-coldfusion/).

Answer (score 1):

For a MYSQL Database reference the code here:
http://www.thehatrack.net/blog/programmatically-creating-new-datasources-in-coldfusion/

For a MSSQL Database reference the code here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fcf.html

In either example, you will still need access to your cfadmin password to access the API since it is an admin feature.

Comment: Links are broken

Answer (score 1):

You could define an `attributeCollection` in your application.cfc file

```
<cfset stData = {}>
<cfset stData.username = 'myusername'>
<cfset stData.password= 'myPassword'>
```

and then use the `attributeCollection` argument in your `cfquery`

```
<cfquery attributecollection="#stData#">
```

You would then have to store your password in this structure, so it's not an ideal process. If you don't have access to the CF Admin or the CF Admin password your options are pretty limited.

Comment: server is a cfquery attribute? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fae.html

Comment: @Travis my main point was to show how to set up a struct to use as an attributeCollection. It wasn't everything necessary.

Comment: I see. I think Kokesh is asking how to create a dsn programmatically. This would still require the dsn to already exist.

Comment: @Travis after I reread the question I think you're right, but it's not explained real well. I'll leave my answer for now unless he clarifies and it becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Since ColdFusion 11 in 2014, this has been possible. The docs are here in [Application variables](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/application-cfc-reference/application-variables.html).

The example from the docs is:

```
// Application.cfc
component {
        this.name = "DSNTest";
        this.datasources = { 
                mssql_app = { 
                    database = "<DBName>", 
                    host = "<HostNameOrIP>", 
                    port = "<portNumber>", 
                    driver = "MSSQLServer", 
                    username = "username", 
                    password = "password" } 
                };
        this.datasource = "mssql_app";
}
```

Comment: (I'm only revisiting old posts on this topic because I'm having some issues with a Application.cfc-defined datasource and was looking for clues. And came across this one)